# cannot resolve method getResource().getColor() error

Tags: java, android, android-adapter, getresource

I am trying to change text color in java code (I dun want to change it at xml)and I know i need to call getResource(). but I get error that "cannot resolve method getResource()".
and i try to declare Context and use context to call getResource() and i get null value.

My java code as below:

```js
public class NewsAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements SectionIndexer, HeadListView.HeaderAdapter, OnScrollListener{
......

@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView,       ViewGroup parent) {
    .......
    NewsEntity news = getItem(position);
        mHolder.item_title.setText(news.getTitle());
        mHolder.comment_count.setText(news.getCommentNum() + "评论");
        mHolder.publish_time.setText(DateTools.getTimeAgo(news.getPublishTime()));//+ "小时前");//getTimefromLong(news.getPublishTime()) + "小时前");
        List<String> imgUrlList = news.getPicList();
        mHolder.popicon.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mHolder.comment_count.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mHolder.right_padding_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if(imgUrlList !=null && imgUrlList.size() !=0){
           // if(imgUrlList.size() == 1){

                    //mHolder.large_image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mHolder.left_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            Picasso.with(activity.getBaseContext()).load(imgUrlList.get(0)).fit().into(mHolder.left_image);
                   // imageLoader.displayImage(imgUrlList.get(0), mHolder.left_image, options);
                   // imageLoader.displayImage(imgUrlList.get(2), mHolder.item_image_2, options);

        }else{
            mHolder.left_image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //mHolder.item_image_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        if(news.getNews_colour() == 0){
            mHolder.item_title.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
        }else if(news.getNews_colour() == 1){
            mHolder.item_title.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
        }
        
......

    }
}
```

My question is how can i change text color at below java code:

```
        if(news.getNews_colour() == 0){
        mHolder.item_title.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
    }else if(news.getNews_colour() == 1){
        mHolder.item_title.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
    }
```

**I'm a newbie at this stuff so any help will be appreciated. Thanks in Advance!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the Context from your views:

```
mHolder.item_title.setTextColor(mHolder.item_title.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
```

Comment: your answer is perfectly solved my problem thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Below approach might help you.

You need to use ContextCompat.getColor(), which is part of the Support V4 Library (so it will work for all the previous API).

```
ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.my_color)
```

You can add the Support V4 library by adding the following to the dependencies array inside your app build.gradle:

`compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'`

Thanks.

Comment: You still need the context to call this.

Comment: but i got error like that:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference

Comment: That's because your context is null, check my answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass your context to NewsAdapter via constructor or setter. And then call `context.getResources.getColor(R.color.black)`

Cheers!

Comment: yes you are right i forgot to give value to context.